# Call all files from a menu

Tags: python

I've got a task to do that is crushing my head. I have five .py documents and I want to make a menu in another .py so I can run any of them by introducing a string inside an `input()` but  don't really see the way to do that and I don't know if there is somehow I can.

I have tried `import` every file to the 6th file but I don't even know how to start.

I would like it just to be seen as simple as it can sound, but yet I find it really hard.

Comment: Can you show what you have done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run them, then try this:-

```
import os
file_path = input("Enter the path of your file = ")
os.system(file_path)
```

- If the file that you are trying to execute is not in the current
  directory, i.e. doesn't exist in the same folder as the currently
  executing python file, then you have to provide it's full path.

  **Path Format:-**. C:\Users\lmYoona\OneDrive\Desktop\example.py
- If the python file you are trying to execute is in the same directory as
  the currently executing python file, then abstract name will also
  work

  **Path Format:-**  example.py

**P.S.:-** I would only recommend this method if all you want is just to execute the other python file, rather then importing stuff from it.